# JAVA Split time into intervals and get random time in an interval

Tags: java, time

I've tried to split time into equal intervals, and then pick a random time in an interval. To give an example : Split time between 8 am and 8 pm, into 4 (it can be 2 or 3 ... ). I'll got 8-11, 11-2, 2-5 and 5-8. Then pick a random time in interval 2 per example, and have 11:32:12.

I began my function with

```
private static List<Interval> splitDateTime(long start, long end, int intervalNo) {
    long interval = (end - start) / intervalNo;
    List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    for (long i = start + interval; i < end; i += interval) {
        list.add(new Interval(start, i));
        start=start + interval;
    }
    list.add(new Interval(start, end));

    for (Interval t:list){
        System.out.println(rant);
    }

    return list;
}
```

So how can I do this ? Do you have some librairies / code / ideas ? Joda ?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: And the error you are having is? What is the question here?

Comment: @MattClark how can I get random time in an interval in list

Comment: I don't think there is some library for this. You need to implement it by yourself as you did. Is there some issue you're having with your solution?

Comment: @Micer I don't know how to get a random time in an interval. May be it exist a method/function allowing to getRandom(long start, long end) ?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on your original question, it looks like what you're really asking here is how you can get a random long value between two intervals. This can be accomplished using Random.

```
import java.util.Random

Random rand = new Random();
long val = rand.nextLong(50); //Returns a random value between 0 and 49
```

So, if you want to get a value within an interval:

```
long val = rand.nextLong([max]-[min]) + [min];
```

Obviously, replacing max with the end of your interval and min with the beginning of your interval.

Edit: forgot to mention, that this will give you a value [min, max) (max is not included). If you want it to be inclusive, just add 1 to the range:

```
long val = rand.nextLong([max]-[min]+1) + [min];
```

Comment: System.out.println(t.getStart() + r.nextLong(t.getEnd() - t.getStart()) );
but it can compil, there is an error about undefine sign -

Answer (score 0):

Without any libraries you can try this code after you got list of intervals from you method and fetched required one:

```
public long getRandomTimeFrom(Interval interval) {
    Random r = new Random(); // random instatnce can be shared as class (static) field
    return interval.getStart() + r.nextLong(interval.getEnd() - interval.getStart());
}
```

Comment: This line doen't work, and eclipse give me any suggestion return interval.getStart() + r.nextLong(interval.getEnd() - interval.getStart());

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SecureRandom s = new SecureRandom();
public Interval randomInterval(long start, long end, int intervalNo) {
    if(intervalNo == 0 || end <= start || (end-start)/intervalNo <= 1){
        return null;
    }
    if(intervalNo == 1){
        return new Interval(start, end);
    }
    System.err.println(start + " "+ end+" "+ intervalNo);
    long interval = (end - start) / (intervalNo);
    long value = Math.abs(s.nextInt(intervalNo));
    long randomStart = start + (value*interval);
    long randomEnd  = start +  ((value+1)*interval);
    if(randomStart < start || randomStart > end || randomEnd <start || randomEnd > end || randomEnd < randomStart){
        throw  new RuntimeException("Start: "+start+" End: "+end+" RandomStart:"+randomStart+" RandomEnd:"+randomEnd);
    }
    return new Interval(randomStart, randomEnd);

}

@org.junit.Test
public void splitDateTime() {
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
        int randomRange = Math.abs(s.nextInt())%100;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long random = s.nextLong();
        long end = start +  (random %10000000+ System.currentTimeMillis())/10;
        System.err.println(i+": "+randomInterval(start, end, randomRange));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed it to :

Comment: I think that you tried to edit @Joe Ledric's answer rather than your own.